# Catching a selected text from the string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

The variable `Field` stores a string like the following:

```
Field = "In Field 'Testing':(Value1) has changed from (1) to (2)"
```

I am looking for a way to extract the field name from that variable and store it a variable called `name`. In the example above, the field name is `Testing`.

Comment: Is there only a single `fieldname` ?

Comment: Yes Something like this     Field= "In Field 'Testing':(Value1) has changed from (1) to (2)" , I want to have name=testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you're looking for is:

`'(.*?)'`

In Python you can write:

```
>>> import re
>>> Field= "In Field 'Testing':(Value1) has changed from (1) to (2)"
>>> print re.findall("'(.*?)'", Field) #Will print Testing
```

After you get `Testing`, I'm sure you'll have no problem to print it like `name=Testing`

---

**Edit**

To print it as you wish, you can:

```
print ''.join(re.findall("'(.*?)'", Field))
```

Comment: Its giving output like this ['Testing']

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Regex:

```
Field.split('\'')[1]
```

Or another way,

```
first_index = Field.index('\'') //Search for first '
second_index = Field.index('\'', first_index+1) //Search for second '
Field[first_index+1:second_index] //"Testing" //Substring
```